# How do I find an installed extension that is no longer found in the marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code gives me the following error: The 1 extension(s) below, in workspace recommendations have issues: johnsoncodehk.volar (not found in marketplace)

How do I find the "johnsoncodehk.volar" extension? I've searched and looked through my installed extensions and I'm not finding this problem extension.

Answer (score 0):

I found and removed a "not found in marketplace" extension in Azure Datastudio (works in vscode too) doing this:

1. enter extensions.json into the Go to File… (Ctrl+P Quick Open, Go to File…)
2. remove the recommended extension.

[image: remove recommended extension]